# Label rotation went wrong

Tags: iphone, objective-c, rotation, label

I would like to do this: [Image](http://i44.tinypic.com/adjocl.png)

In my storyboard I put the labels like this: [Image](http://i43.tinypic.com/mjb7l2.png)

Every label is 70Widht and 20Height

Labels are named:

```
label1 (position x:20 y:161)
label2 (position x:50 y:161)
label3 (position x:80 y:161)
label4 (position x:110 y:161)
label5 (position x:140 y:161)
label6 (position x:170 y:161)
label7 (position x:200 y:161)
label8 (position x:230 y:161)
label9 (position x:260 y:161)
label10 (position x:290 y:161)
```

in my ViewController.h:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label2;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label3;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label4;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label5;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label6;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label7;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label8;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label9;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label10;
```

in my ViewController.m in the ViewDidLoad method:

```
[label1 setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI / 2)];
[label2 setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI / 2)];
[label3 setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI / 2)];
[label4 setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI / 2)];
[label5 setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI / 2)];
[label6 setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI / 2)];
[label7 setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI / 2)];
[label8 setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI / 2)];
[label9 setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI / 2)];
[label10 setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI / 2)];
```

but when I run the simulator something is wrong: [Image](http://i42.tinypic.com/2zsnyia.png)

the first five labels are ok but the other five are in random positions.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IB, start with a superview that will contain all the labels.  Place the labels in that containing superview stacked top to bottom, left justified ... just how you'd expect to see them if they weren't rotated.

Set up an outlet to the containing superview, and apply a single `-M_PI/2` transform to it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
label1.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DegreesToRadians(270));
```

and so on.

> also define
>
> ## define DegreesToRadians(x) ((x) * M_PI / 180.0)

Comment: With your solution the problem doesn't go away